# Hover (mouseleave) method not showing effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of images which change their image when hovering on them and also a div animate (as an overlay) on the image during hover.

The code is as follow:

```
// hide overlays
$(".mini-shop .item .image a div").hide();

// toggle overlay and second image
$(".mini-shop .item .image").hover(
    function() {
        $img = $(this).find('a img');
        $img.stop().hide();
        var src = $img.attr('src');
        $img.attr('src', $img.attr('data-csrc'));
        $img.stop().fadeIn(300);
        $img.attr('data-csrc', src);
        $(this).find('a div').stop().animate({
            'top': '80%'
        }, 300).css('display', 'block');
    },
    function() {
        $img = $(this).find('a img');
        $img.stop().fadeOut(100);
        var src = $img.attr('src');
        $img.attr('src', $img.attr('data-csrc'));
        $img.stop().fadeIn(300);
        $img.attr('data-csrc', src);
        $(this).find('a div').stop().animate({
            'top': '100%'
        }, 300).css('display', 'none');
    }
);
```

my problem is, only the effects in the first function (mouseenter) work and in the mouseleave method the overlay disappears immediately and the fade effect does not work! What is the problem of this code?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may be a bit of a hassle, but have you tried separating them into one mouseenter() function and the other a mouseleave()? I know the hover() is supposed to cover both, however, I see no errors in your code so I cannot propose much more than to do what I have said.

Comment: I tried separate mouse enter and leave but the result is exactly the same.